# Share of invoiced in total (sum group by)

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I have sales lines some of them are invoiced, some not. I would like to add information of invoiced lines share per each order (salesid). I want this information for each sales line to be the same within one order. Invoiced line has sales status =3. Here's my try:

```
SELECT  
salesid,linenum,itemid,salesstatus,name,lineamount
,(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN salesstatus=3 THEN lineamount ELSE 0 END) as expr1) invoiced
,(SELECT SUM (lineamount) as expr2 GROUP BY salesid) total
,invoiced/total
FROM T.SALESLINES 
GROUP BY
salesid,linenum,itemid,salesstatus,name,lineamount
```

Grouping by salesid does not work giving error "*Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference*." 
I guess the code seems logical but does not work. So how should I group by salesid to divide invoiced by total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Select *,invoiced/total as ColName from (
SELECT  
salesid,linenum,itemid,salesstatus,name,lineamount
,(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN salesstatus=3 THEN lineamount ELSE 0 END From T.SALESLINES) as invoiced
,(SELECT SUM (lineamount)From T.SALESLINES GROUP BY salesid) as total
FROM T.SALESLINES) source
GROUP BY
salesid,linenum,itemid,salesstatus,name,lineamount,invoiced,total
```

Comment: Nope. _Subquery returned more than 1 value_

Comment: Found solution!
'(select(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN salesstatus=3 THEN lineamount ELSE 0 END) from T.salesline T2 where T2.salesid=T1.salesid group by T2.salesid)
/
(select sum(T2.lineamount) from T.salesline T2 where T2.salesid=T1.salesid group by T2.salesid)) as 'Invoiced%'
from T.salesline T1'